# Make a ListBox Fill the Width of the Parent Container

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls

I have a DockPanel with a listbox in it.  The dockpanel successfully fills the width of the entire window.  Now, i want the Listbox to fill the width of the entire DockPanel.

I have tried many things... including wrapping a grid around it and setting the column to width of *, setting the horizontalalignment of the listbox to stretch, and numerous others.  I cannot seem to get this silly listbox to fill the width.

This listbox DOES have an ItemTemplate, but everything inside it has a horizontal alignment of stretch with auto width.  Whenever you set the ItemTemplate's width to something static, the listbox does resize appropriately.  I just cannot get it to fill the parent.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks guys for making me realize it's my fault... Turns out it was a goof in the style Tag.

I will attempt to remove this question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ListBox should fill the DockPanel by defualt.

I just tried:

```
<DockPanel>
  <ListBox Background="Red" />
</DockPanel>
```

and it worked perfectly. Will be hard for us to see what the problem is without a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 5):

I would bet that your ListBox is filling the width of its parent container, but the ListBoxItems within your list box are not stretching horizontally. Try adding the  following style:

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter> 
     </Style> 
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DockPanel.LastChildFill` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove all 'alignment' properties from the listbox to get this to work.  Be sure that the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment assignments are removed from the listbox definition.  Once I did this AND wrapped it in a DockPanel, as suggested above, I was able to get it to work.